# Does FireFox or Chrome store raw HTML files in cache?

Tags: firefox, google-chrome, browser, browser-cache, cache-control

I'm currently looking at FF and Chrome cache files and can't find what I'm looking for. 
I'm looking for raw html file like you would see if you would click `'View Source Code'`. 
And if it does not store it automatically, do you know any way I can configure FF or Chrome to save html files in cache?

Comment: Different browsers store cache  in different ways. I remember FF storage in sqlite but cache in disk cache.forums.mozillazine.org/viewtopic.php?f=23&t=645169&start=0

Answer (score 2, accepted):

`about:cache` will let you browse your cache in Firefox or Chrome.

Have fun running `gunzip` on hex dumps you've saved in your favorite hex editor.

You can strip out the information surrounding the raw hex relatively easily with a fixed-width split in your favorite spreadsheet program. Using a hex editor, paste the raw hex into a new document, save it, then `gunzip` it. If the document was not gzipped to begin with (no `Content-Encoding: gzip` in the headers) then the HTML should already be in the rightmost column.

Comment: Actually, at least Firefox stores all files compressed in cache, even the ones that did not have `Content-Encoding: gzip`.  See https://bugzilla.mozilla.org/show_bug.cgi?id=648429